# Invalid data argument when using plot

Tags: matlab, plot

I have a problem with the following MATLAB code:

```
E=1.15*10^5; 
h=0.35; 
b=50; 
l=75; 
i0=(b*h^3)/12;
f=0:1:10; 
P=[0 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.3 0.4 0.6 0.7 0.8 1.1 1.4];
Pt=(E*2*10^5*f)/l^3;

plot(f, P,'k','LineWidth', 2, f, Pt, '-.k', 'LineWidth', 2); grid; 

xlabel('Sageata f[mm]'); 
ylabel('Forta P[N]'); 
legend('P',  'P_t'); 
title('Caracteristica arcului triunghiular');
```

> Error using plot
>
> Invalid first data argument

First of all, what is `k` and `-k` and why my is plot not working without them? Secondly why do I only have one line?

Comment: please use code formatting (the fat `{}` button atop of the question editor) instead of these empty lines. Don't but multiple statements on one line - that's only confusing, and you don't pay per line.

Comment: For your first question, check the doc about [`LineSpec`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html#btzitot_sep_mw_3a76f056-2882-44d7-8e73-c695c0c54ca8)

Answer (score 1):

If you want tight control of line parameters, its much better to just separate each line you want to plot in a separate `plot` call.

```
hold on
plot(f, P,'k','LineWidth', 2)
plot(f, Pt, '-.k', 'LineWidth', 2); 
grid; 
hold off
```